# Is Hope saying that he's feeling that "something bad's about to happen" intended to be a boss battle warning?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

Starting from about Chapter 9 or 10, before several boss fights, with Hope in the battle team, I often hear Hope saying the following:

> Why do I have this feeling something bad's about to happen?

Is this intended to be a boss battle warning?  If so, do other characters say similar things?

Comment: Foreshadowing!  Not so much a warning for a boss battle as it is just story plot.

Comment: @fbueckert: Consider expanding upon your comment and posting it as an answer.